# Chamar função em JavaScript após leitura de um JSON

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade, no qual se trata de um e-commerce. 
E tenho uma dúvida referente a seguinte questão, eu preciso chamar uma função apenas após o carregamento de alguns arquivos JSON que tenho em meu projeto. 
Preciso fazer isso, pelo fato de que estou fazendo um carrossel de produtos, e esse carrossel só poderá ser construído, quando eu carregar dinamicamente todos os meus produtos.

Abaixo está as funções que precisam ser feitas antes de executar o carrossel:

- Função genérica, para evitar chamar muitas funções.

  ```js
  function loadProdutos() {
      findJogosPs4();
      findJogosXbox();
      findJogosNintendo();
  }
  ```
- Essa função abaixo é semelhantes as demais que estou chamando no 'load produtos':

  ```js
  function findJogosPs4() {
      let produtosPs4 = new Array();
      $.getJSON('repository/produtosPs4.json', function (data) {
      data.jogosPs4.forEach(function (jogo) {
          newProduto = new Produto(
              jogo.id,
              jogo.nome,
              jogo.preco,
              jogo.caminhoCapa,
              jogo.qtdeParcelas,
              jogo.descontoAvista);
          produtosPs4.push(newProduto);
      });
      montaJogos(produtosPs4, '#gamePs');
      });
   }
  ```

  E esse é o carroussel que preciso chamar após buscar todos os produtos:

  ```js
  function carrossel() {
  $('.jogos').slick({
      dots: true,
      speed: 600,
      autoplaySpeed: 2500,
      autoplay: false,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
          {
              breakpoint: 1024,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 3,
                  dots: true
              }
          },
          {
              breakpoint: 760,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 2,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  dots: false
              }
          },
          {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  dots: false
              }
          }
      ]
  });
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a método `.done()` do Jquery para fazer isso, ele irá fazer algo quando finalizar o processamento do Json, pelo que vi no seu código ele ficaria assim.

```
function findJogosPs4() {
 let produtosPs4 = new Array();
 $.getJSON('repository/produtosPs4.json', function (data) {
 data.jogosPs4.forEach(function (jogo) {
    newProduto = new Produto(
        jogo.id,
        jogo.nome,
        jogo.preco,
        jogo.caminhoCapa,
        jogo.qtdeParcelas,
        jogo.descontoAvista);
    produtosPs4.push(newProduto);
 })
  montaJogos(produtosPs4, '#gamePs');
 }).done(function(){
    carrossel();
 });
}
```

Aqui você pode ver como funciona melhor os outros métodos.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Valeu cara, eu tinha visto esse método .done() em alguns sites, porém não sabia como aplicar da forma certa. O único problema que deu é que se eu chamar em todos as minhas funções, a biblioteca que estou utilizando para o carrousel, dispara um erro. Entretanto coloquei apenas na última função de busca que faço, e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!